# Alteryx: Create several rows from a range in a string

Tags: alteryx

I'm looking for a way to use Alteryx for the following data wrangling task.

I have a table like this:

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1-3 |
| B | 0-2 |

and I would like that to result in this:

I have a table like this:

| Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 0 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |

So I'm trying to "break open" the list of numbers in `Var2` and create a row for every possible number in the range.

Comment: Could you do a GenerateRows tool to generate integers from 0 to some  number larger than your max(Var2)... then join that to your table (cartesian product), then filter on GeneratedRow >= Var1 and <= Var2?

Answer (score 0):

I extended on the answer of  @johnjps111: Use a GenerateRows tool, but for `Initialization Expression` use the start value. and for `Condition Expression` force the new column (e.g. "RowCount") to be RowCount <= EndValue.

No join necessary in this way!

Answer (score 0):

And to make it more clear, the initialization expression would be something like:

```
(regex_replace([var2],"(\d+).*","$1"))
```

and the condition expression would be something like:

```
RowCount <=  tonumber(regex_replace([var2],".*(\d+)$","$1"))
```